# Prestashop module payment hook not triggering

Tags: php, module, prestashop, payment, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop 1.6.1.6 needs to make some API calls in the payment hook. However for some reason the hook is not triggering and hookPayment method is not executing. When comparing with Paypal module that has also hookPayment then this hook is executed. What I am doing wrong?

Module code is as simple as possible

```
<?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class TestModule extends Module
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'testmodule';
        $this->tab = 'shipping_logistics';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Test Module');
        $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

        $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');
    }

    public function install()
    {
        if (!parent::install() || !$this->registerHook('payment'))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
        if (!parent::uninstall())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function hookPayment($params)
    {
        ddd($params);
    }
}
```

After installing the hook is registered in database

```
mysql> select * from module where id_module=75;
+-----------+------------+--------+---------+
| id_module | name       | active | version |
+-----------+------------+--------+---------+
|        75 | testmodule |      1 | 1.0.0   |
+-----------+------------+--------+---------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from hook_module where id_module=75;
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+
| id_module | id_shop | id_hook | position |
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+
|        75 |       1 |       1 |        4 |
+-----------+---------+---------+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from hook where id_hook=1;
+---------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
| id_hook | name           | title   | description                                         | position | live_edit |
+---------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
|       1 | displayPayment | Payment | This hook displays new elements on the payment page |        1 |         1 |
+---------+----------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

You made a typo in your function name, it says `public function hoolPayment($params)`, but should be `public function hookPayment($params)`.

Comment: Great answer! Fixed the typo and resetted the module but still nothing. I have played before also without the typo

Comment: How are you checking if it enters the hook? (are you logging it to a file, or just doing a die() )

Comment: ddd($params); in paypal module prints tons of variable values. In my test module it does not print anything

Comment: Are you sure  you don't have any other module hooked on  this awell, that is dieing before your module? You can verify this in your backend (Goto Modules -> Positions -> Search for payment).

Comment: Yes I am sure. I found the answer after some more research and reading the code. I posted for others to see as well.

Answer (score 2):

PrestaShop module needs to extend PaymentModule during the installation for the ability to trigger payment hook. Just changing the extends nor reset do not help.